# Confluent Kafka Python Library blocking asyncio consumer poll

Tags: apache-kafka, python-asyncio, confluent-kafka-python, aiokafka

I have a function which I call via asyncio.create_task()

```
async def runthis():
    c = Consumer({
        'bootstrap.servers': 'server:9092',
        'group.id': 'mygroup',
        'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest',
        'message.max.bytes':500000,
        'fetch.wait.max.ms':1000,
        'fetch.min.bytes':500000,
        'fetch.max.bytes':500000
    })

    c.subscribe(['queuestore'])
    print("Started")
    while True:
        msgs = c.poll(timeout=2000)
```

Unfortunately, I do not get any messages in this. Is there any issue with usage of asyncio for confluent kafka python library. It works well with usage of aiokafka.

Comment: I don't think aiokafka uses the Confluent library

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could complete your example with the imports and minimal boiler plate so we can check what each element is.

But from the snippet as presented, the `Consumer.poll` call is done synchronously, so it will block the asyncio loop. Check if there are async versions of these kafka methods to be called, otherwise, they should be called with `asyncio.run_in_executor(...)`  and properly awaited.